# Group chat flutter screen rebuilding on small changes in an single message?? How to optimize it

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I am trying to make an community app but the main problem is in community chat screen my whole widget is again rebuilding on an small change in a single message in an realtime database

Here is my chat screen

```
body: StreamBuilder(
  stream: messageStream,
  builder: ((context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done ||
        snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      } else {
        List<dynamic> messages =
            snapshot.data!.snapshot.children.toList();
          messages.forEach((element) {
          print(element.value['from']);
          })   ;
        // messages.sort()    
        int n = messages.length;
        return ListView.builder(
            // shrinkWrap: true,
            // primary: false,
            cacheExtent: double.maxFinite,
            reverse: true,
            keyboardDismissBehavior:
                ScrollViewKeyboardDismissBehavior.onDrag,
            itemCount: messages.length,
            itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
              // return Text("HI");
              print(messages[index]);
              return MessageCard(
                key: ValueKey(messages[index]),
                index: n - 1 - index,
                messages: messages,
              );
            }));
        
      }
    } else {
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    }
  }),
),
```

My message card is an simple statelesswidget

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that any other optimization solution but as far as my knowledge for performance optimization, consider using Slivers instead of ListView. Additionally, since you are using ValueKey, Flutter can efficiently identify each message widget individually.

Comment: But is key helpful

Comment: Yes for uniquely identify a widget